# What is this 19th century British army uniform?

Tags: 19th-century, uniform

I believe this chap is a distant relative of mine. It is in a large photo album my granny had but of course no names anywhere.
On the back of this photo it is noted "Sept 1881" taken in Edinburgh.

[image: British army]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sub-lieutenant of one of the Rifle regiments.  Off hand, judging from his cross belt, actually a cartridge pouch belt - the cartridge box being on his back, I would place him in the 26-90 Regiments of Foot, The Cameronians (Scottish Rifles).  With the 90th Regiment of Foot (Perthshire Light Infantry) forming the 2d Battalion of the 26th Regiment of Foot (The Cameronians) in 1881 (one of the many regimental amalgamations of the [Childers Reforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childers_Reforms)), the new regiment became a Rifle Regiment and adopted the green jacket of the Rifle Corps initially with green trousers but soon in tartan trews of the universal pattern.  In 1891 they adopted trews in the Douglas pattern.
(Also see Bowling, A.H., Scottish Regiments 1660-1914, Almark Publications, 1970, page 20.)

The distinctive cross belt can be seen [here](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/426856870916498438/), while the caption says Rifle Brigade, the gents are clearly displaying the Cameronian regimental badge, [seen here](http://www.uniformology.com/INSIGNIA-03.html), scroll down to the fourth display, on their cross belts.  Another Cameronian officer, in review order, minus the braid on the jacket, so probably a little bit later, say, 1905, maybe 1908, can be seen [here](https://www.historylinksarchive.org.uk/picture/number8172.asp) again with the distinctive belt devices.  One might note the difference between the Cameronian belt devices and those of the Kings Royal Rifles [here](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/417357090442310327/).